# cvs update and delete old files

Tags: version-control, cvs

I have an old branch on cvs called myapp_release_7
after I deployed that branch, I modified the trunk code and I created a new release branch
myapp_release_8

the release 8 contains new files (java new classes)

While I am deploying to test environment, I submitted this command

```
cvs -d {server} update -C -P -d -r "myapp_release_8"
```

it worked fine.
But I wanted to rollback so I submitted this command

```
cvs -d {server} update -C -P -d -r "myapp_release_7"
```

but the new files that were added by release 8 didn't get deleted after this command.

any idea why ?